# Sending Cisco commands from a text file using Netmiko fails. send_config_set works but send_config_from_file doesn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming, cisco-ios, netmiko

- I have been using this link as guide.

[https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/book/18_ssh_telnet/netmiko.html#:~:text=Netmiko%20is%20a%20module%20that,pip%20install%20netmiko](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/book/18_ssh_telnet/netmiko.html#:%7E:text=Netmiko%20is%20a%20module%20that,pip%20install%20netmiko)

```
XXXXXX:/Test # cat test2.py
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

with open('commands_ios') as f:
    commands_list = f.read().splitlines()

cisco_D = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'host':   '10.1.1.1',
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password',
}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_D)
output = net_connect.send_config_from_file('commands_ios.txt')
print(output)
```

XXXXXX:/Test # python3 test2.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 14, in <module>
    output = net_connect.send_config_from_file('commands_ios.txt')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1808, in send_config_from_file
    with io.open(config_file, "rt", encoding="utf-8") as cfg_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'commands_ios.txt'
AL108564:/Test #
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use readlines instead of splitlines as follows. And if ypu have a .txt > you should change it like this => 'commands_ios.txt'

```
with open('commands_ios.txt') as f:
    commands_list = f.readlines() #(or commands_list = f.splitlines())
    
    #commands_list = "".join(commands_list ) => If you need convert string
    #commands_list = lines.strip() => If you need remove spaces
    #print(commands_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The script works alright; `commands_ios.txt` file consisted of Cisco show commands which is usually entered in enable mode, `send_config_from_file` only enters commands in Global Config mode only hence it was throwing an error.